# Unable to add LSTM layer on top of embedded layer on GPU - Keras with tensorflow backend

Tags: deep-learning, keras, lstm, tensorflow

Below is the code snippet:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Embedding

lang_model = Sequential()
lang_model.add(Embedding(1000, 100, input_length=25))
lang_model.add(LSTM(100,return_sequences=True)) #stuck here

lang_model.summary()
```

When I run the above code on my local CPU, it runs fine, but when running on a GPU on google cloud, it just doesn't work. It doesn't even show any error, its just gets stuck on the 3rd line.

Please suggest.

Just figured out that it works fine with theano backend, but fails when I use tensorflow backend.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the `CuDNNLSTM`? -- Not sure it will work, but it might... You could also try to pass `unroll=True` to your LSTM layer.

Comment: Tried both, but still facing the same problem.

Comment: Weird.... I can only think you've got some installation problem with one of these: Cuda 8.0; CuDNN 6.1; Tensorflow-gpu; Keras. But I have no idea about what it could be...